# Some ASCII art for N64's 20th B-Day

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

The official release of the Nintendo 64 in North America was on September 29, 1996.<sup>[[1]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nintendo_64)</sup> I figured that this anniversary deserved an ASCII art challenge. There's one small twist though, you have to output a different ASCII art for each of three different inputs.

If the input is `1`, output this ASCII art of an N64 Controller: <sub>[(source)](http://osrevad.westopia.net/asciicontrollers.php)</sub>

```
                 | |
             _,.-'-'-.,_
      ______|           |______
   ,-'      |  NINTENDO |      `-.
 ,'   _                          `.
/   _| |_                     (^)   \
|  |_   _|                  (<) (>) |
\    |_|         (S)     (B)  (v)   /
|`.              ___       (A)    ,'|
|  `-.______   ,' _ `.   ______,-'  |
|      |    `. | (_) | ,'    |      |
|      |      \`.___,'/      |      |
|      |      |       |      |      |
|      /      |       |      \      |
\     /       |       |       \     /
 `._,'        \       /        `._,'
               \     /
                `._,'
```

If the input is `2`, output this ASCII art of the N64 logo:<sub>[(source)](http://www.asciiartfarts.com/20020320.html)</sub>

```
                  .-"-.
               .-"     "-.
              /"-.     .-|
             /    "-.-"  |
            /      /     |
   .-"-.   /      /      |       .-"-.
.-"     "-/      /       |    .-"     "-.
|-.     .-"\    /        |   /"-.     .-|
|  '-.-"    \  /         | /'    "-.-"  |
|     \      \/   .-"-.  /'        |    |
|      \      \.-"     "-.         |    |
|       \      |-.     .-"\        |    |
|        \     |  "-.-"    '\      |    |
|         \    |    |        '\    |    |
|    |\    \   |    |          '\  |    |
|    | \    \  |    |            '\|    |
|    |  \    \ |    |    :\.            |
|    |   \    \|    |    |  \.          |
|    |    \         |    |    \.        |
'-.  |  .-"\        |    |    '.\.    .-'
   "-|-"    \       |    |      "-\.-"
             \      |    |
              \     |    |
               "-.  |  .-'
                  "-|-"
```

Finally, if the input is `3`, outout this ASCII art of a console and TV: <sub>[(source)](http://nintendo64.ascii.uk/)</sub>

```
              o
     o       /
      \     /
       \   /
        \ /
   ______________
  |.------------.|
  ||            ||
  ||            ||
  ||            ||
  ||            ||
  ||____________||_
  |OO ....... OO | `-.
  '------_.-._---' _.'  
   _____||   ||___/_
  /  _.-|| N ||-._  \      .-._
 / -'_.---------._'- \    ,'___i-i___
/_.-'_  NINTENDO _'-._\  ' /_+  o :::\
|`-i /m\/m\|\|/=,/m\i-'| | || \ O / ||
|  |_\_/\_/___\_/'./|  | | \/  \ /  \/
`-'              '-.`-'  ,      V
                    `---'
```

### Rules:

- Input may be either as a number or a string/char.
- You may have any amount of leading or trailing spaces and trailing or leading newlines. (Output must be aligned correctly though)
- Your submission may be either a full program or a function.
- No retrieving the ASCII art from the internet.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so smallest byte count wins.

Comment: @Emigna I realigned the cord and took the liberty of altering the controller to look better, as nobody has submitted any solutions yet.

Comment: I'd suggest restricting this to just the N. The others are probably too intricate to do efficiently except with plain string compression which is rather boring.

Comment: There's a `'` or two in the N that I feel should be `"`. It's bothering me.

Answer (score 6):

## Javascript ES6, 1175 bytes

Using a simple [Run Length Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) to encode just the spaces.

```js
let F=
  
  z=>[(f=d=>d.replace(/\d+/g,e=>' '.repeat(e)))(`17|1|
13_,.-'-'-.,_
6______|11|______
3,-'6|2NINTENDO1|6\`-.
1,'3_26\`.
/3_|1|_21(^)3\\
|2|_3_|18(<)1(>)1|
\\4|_|9(S)5(B)2(v)3/
|\`.14___7(A)4,'|
|2\`-.______3,'1_1\`.3______,-'2|
|6|4\`.1|1(_)1|1,'4|6|
|6|6\\\`.___,'/6|6|
|6|6|7|6|6|
|6/6|7|6\\6|
\\5/7|7|7\\5/
1\`._,'8\\7/8\`._,'
15\\5/
16\`._,'`),f(`18.-"-.
15.-"5"-.
14/"-.5.-|
13/4"-.-"2|
12/6/5|
3.-"-.3/6/6|7.-"-.
.-"5"-/6/7|4.-"5"-.
|-.5.-"\\4/8|3/"-.5.-|
|2'-.-"4\\2/9|1/'4"-.-"2|
|5\\6\\/3.-"-.2/'8|4|
|6\\6\\.-"5"-.9|4|
|7\\6|-.5.-"\\8|4|
|8\\5|2"-.-"4'\\6|4|
|9\\4|4|8'\\4|4|
|4|\\4\\3|4|10'\\2|4|
|4|1\\4\\2|4|12'\\|4|
|4|2\\4\\1|4|4:\\.12|
|4|3\\4\\|4|4|2\\.10|
|4|4\\9|4|4\\.8|
'-.2|2.-"\\8|4|4'.\\.4.-'
3"-|-"4\\7|4|6"-\\.-"
13\\6|4|
14\\5|4|
15"-.2|2.-'
18"-|-"`),f(`14o
5o7/
6\\5/
7\\3/
8\\1/
3______________
2|.------------.|
2||12||
2||12||
2||12||
2||12||
2||____________||_
2|OO1.......1OO1|1\`-.
2'------_.-._---'1_.'2
3_____||3||___/_
2/2_.-||1N1||-._2\\6.-._
1/1-'_.---------._'-1\\4,'___i-i___
/_.-'_2NINTENDO1_'-._\\2'1/_+2o1:::\\
|\`-i1/m\\/m\\|\\|/=,/m\\i-'|1|1||1\\1O1/1||
|2|_\\_/\\_/___\\_/'./|2|1|1\\/2\\1/2\\/
\`-'14'-.\`-'2,6V
20\`---'`)][z-1]

G=_=>h.innerHTML = F(a.value)

h.innerHTML = F(1)
```

```html
<input id=a onchange="G()" type="number" value="1"></input>
<pre id=h>
```

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>907</s> <s>904</s> 903 bytes

Implements a compression by successive substitutions of the most frequent sub-strings.

This can be compressed significantly more (down to about 850 bytes) by assuming Windows-125x encoding and using replacement characters in the range `0xA0` - `0xFF`. But the result is just ugly. :-)

```js
let f =

n=>[...Array(78)].map((_,i)=>s=~":<=>ABNOSV\\^_`imov|".indexOf((c=String.fromCharCode(125-i)))?s:s.split(c).join(['\\','NINTENDO',`
`][c]||"9|XsD'RE405398T08kU8K0\"-G/'0|W7/;_E/C62G5|557970..-\"6_ /|52F8@04D\"`.-','??7 25\";7|3 3|4 .-662|---. |4|43__4433  ".substr(k+=2,2)),s="c99JE_,zP;,_27fX39fe,PH3197`;2 MG_cwQ2/G_|9_cE(^)G0@F_G_Xw(<) (>)9208_X (S)E(B)3(v)n@Q57ZK(A)4M|@3`;fGM _ QGf,PF@H4Q9 (_)9 M8H@HaQZM/HH@HHbHH@jHbaH20gbbqg2 Q_M50K/5Q_MJqgJ5Q_M~c3DIJKyIJjIED|Jg4I[FJ4/j49eDInjHKDI2yp/jb4yI@;ERT/dnIED|@3';[x3/59Y'4I[F@E0a/GDI3/'dUaayI59UqH;ER0dU5T93I[4lHU5 0885l8rt3uwlFr tF854l|r3tu4:0.5rGt|8830.5F@8x5ux.d2';F3R0d84'.0.4zep|[xb87p0RJE0H8J7TuJKIF3zJwp|[~57o2EoK/2ag2qnJ0YeCCfW.LL?-;k{{{{|CCC||_WOO ]]]. OO9 `;23'L?_.h?P _.'eC_||3}Z/_23/3_D|| N}h307.h2Y P_.LLh'- TMZi-iZ2/_z_31 _'h03'Y_+3o :::0@`-iYm0/m0|0|/=,/m0iP|9} 0 OY}@F_0_/0_/Z0_/'./|F9 0/30Y30/2`P57';`P3,7VJ54`?P",k=-2)&&s.split`~`[n-1]

console.log(f(1));
console.log(f(2));
console.log(f(3));
```

#### Making-Of

The above JS was generated with the following PHP script, where `"n64.txt"` is basically the concatenation of the 3 original pictures separated with `~` characters.

```php
<?php
  $str = file_get_contents("n64.txt");

  // ignore line-breaks between 2 pictures
  $str = str_replace("~\n", "~", $str);

  // replace backslashes with 0's
  $str = str_replace("\\", "0", $str);

  // replace 'NINTENDO' with 1's to have more uppercase letters
  // available as replacement characters
  $str = str_replace("NINTENDO", "1", $str);

  // replace line-breaks with 2's
  $str = str_replace("\n", "2", $str);

  // $skipped is the list of characters that can't be used as replacement
  // characters (backslash + anything existing in the original string)
  $skipped = '';

  // $dic is the replacement dictionary
  $dic = '';

  for($i = 0; $i < 75; $i++) {
    // $r = current replacement character
    $r = chr(51 + $i);

    // can we use it?
    if($r == "\\" || strpos($str, $r) !== false) {
      $skipped .= $r;
      continue;
    }

    // look for the most frequent 2-character sub-string
    $count = array();

    for($n = 0; $n < strlen($str) - 1; $n++) {
      $s = substr($str, $n, 2);
      $count[$s] = isset($count[$s]) ? $count[$s] : 0;
      $count[$s]++;
    }

    asort($count);
    $keys = array_keys($count);
    $s = array_pop($keys);

    // add it to the dictionary
    $dic = $s.$dic;

    // replace all occurences with the replacement character
    $str = str_replace($s, $r, $str);

    printf("'%s' => '%s' %d\n", $s, $r, strlen($str));
  }

  // generate JS
  file_put_contents(
    "n64.js",
    sprintf(
      "n=>[...Array(78)].map((_,i)=>".
      "s=~\"%s\".indexOf((c=String.fromCharCode(125-i)))?s:".
      "s.split(c).join(['\\\\','NINTENDO',`\n`][c]||\"%s\".substr(k+=2,2)),".
      "s=\"%s\",k=-2)".
      "&&s.split`~`[n-1]",
      str_replace("\\", "\\\\", $skipped),
      str_replace('"', '\"', $dic),
      $str
    )
  );
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Racket, 1059 bytes

```rkt
(require file/gunzip net/base64)(display((λ(o)(gunzip-through-ports(open-input-bytes(base64-decode(list-ref'(#"H4sICMov7lcCAzEAdZExDsMgDEV3TuENkAhcoKrUqh2ypEM7osIpOvnwtTEkgaaOFIvvZ8efAAyBgKoTkvOTpse7VAupBO6bROK6m3QbBMu8vO7L7QGVzZNX4Lie4G9krwITtMgxZd6W3lEhCNFt0piTBXO25CXKfhtjnlbylbL58CEozL4fQG4afym808hfJAvitUjkozSKVKwXqvpnM5RNokXEd7uJniI3mcc6HTp1pBCOjisVDqnYqLiHRqpiQdHKyWno1K1Lqmq47bX351cy/AXpeU7EYwIAAA=="#"H4sICNkv7lcCAzIAbdIxDgQhCAXQfk5BbKzUfs/CUTj8qiACMo2J/xl/cADi11tp/Xs39/pGY24JIR8NObCO+mjYZUf70pgAuUq3g1fMbEPSSgUt3NIVnhu1yVE0cMpRXX/ugpziuJ3ZaY8jlZpikMtDY+1ECiUtNvtjLpmSnaNYKwkP9ZKtk3BolMt6eeiVP+z2wJVCyZa11kjAMECe75V1DZCyAe6SnW1v9dvvQfruEEdV2no3/z/7OUOSpRE/POm9Tzpr/AEE2h7HhgMAAA=="#"H4sICOIv7lcCAzMApVG7DsIwDNzzFd48UNt7JTYYWNoFMUVy1gyIH/DHc0l4tBIb1yjxXf1MiLZ4pHG8qA1Kecc6/RCwbvsOUEJlA40mxbZY/Clt64E1bV1JBwhmUBGFzKMFV1HHyeTKRJ+me/KezloSg6wCcYGIiPf41MITfgv7dzR1luEwMTJUqW16gwcjcrks1/NyWgle6nBjMj+0C57nOacoUsnuGSty2HGCUYUDnaN+phXVMCz6C89uWEiOndWahi9bfwBslgom2wE1uzYNekv0A6XfyBPSqZrcBwIAAA==")(-(read)1))))o)(get-output-string o))(open-output-string)))
```

Just gzipped data encoded as base64.

### Ungolfed

```rkt
(require file/gunzip net/base64)
(display ((λ (o)
            (gunzip-through-ports
             (open-input-bytes
              (base64-decode
               (list-ref
                '(#"H4sICMov7lcCAzEAdZExDsMgDEV3TuENkAhcoKrUqh2ypEM7osIpOvnwtTEkgaaOFIvvZ8efAAyBgKoTkvOTpse7VAupBO6bROK6m3QbBMu8vO7L7QGVzZNX4Lie4G9krwITtMgxZd6W3lEhCNFt0piTBXO25CXKfhtjnlbylbL58CEozL4fQG4afym808hfJAvitUjkozSKVKwXqvpnM5RNokXEd7uJniI3mcc6HTp1pBCOjisVDqnYqLiHRqpiQdHKyWno1K1Lqmq47bX351cy/AXpeU7EYwIAAA=="
                  #"H4sICNkv7lcCAzIAbdIxDgQhCAXQfk5BbKzUfs/CUTj8qiACMo2J/xl/cADi11tp/Xs39/pGY24JIR8NObCO+mjYZUf70pgAuUq3g1fMbEPSSgUt3NIVnhu1yVE0cMpRXX/ugpziuJ3ZaY8jlZpikMtDY+1ECiUtNvtjLpmSnaNYKwkP9ZKtk3BolMt6eeiVP+z2wJVCyZa11kjAMECe75V1DZCyAe6SnW1v9dvvQfruEEdV2no3/z/7OUOSpRE/POm9Tzpr/AEE2h7HhgMAAA=="
                  #"H4sICOIv7lcCAzMApVG7DsIwDNzzFd48UNt7JTYYWNoFMUVy1gyIH/DHc0l4tBIb1yjxXf1MiLZ4pHG8qA1Kecc6/RCwbvsOUEJlA40mxbZY/Clt64E1bV1JBwhmUBGFzKMFV1HHyeTKRJ+me/KezloSg6wCcYGIiPf41MITfgv7dzR1luEwMTJUqW16gwcjcrks1/NyWgle6nBjMj+0C57nOacoUsnuGSty2HGCUYUDnaN+phXVMCz6C89uWEiOndWahi9bfwBslgom2wE1uzYNekv0A6XfyBPSqZrcBwIAAA==")
                (- (read) 1))))
             o)
            (get-output-string o))
          (open-output-string)))
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>2113</s> 2112 bytes

If nobody else is going to compete I'll just grab the trophy and leave..

```
<?php function a($n){if($n<2){?>
                 | |
             _,.-'-'-.,_
      ______|           |______
   ,-'      |  NINTENDO |      `-.
 ,'   _                          `.
/   _| |_                     (^)   \
|  |_   _|                  (<) (>) |
\    |_|         (S)     (B)  (v)   /
|`.              ___       (A)    ,'|
|  `-.______   ,' _ `.   ______,-'  |
|      |    `. | (_) | ,'    |      |
|      |      \`.___,'/      |      |
|      |      |       |      |      |
|      /      |       |      \      |
\     /       |       |       \     /
 `._,'        \       /        `._,'
               \     /
                `._,'<?php }else if($n==2){?>
                  .-"-.
               .-"     "-.
              /"-.     .-|
             /    "-.-"  |
            /      /     |
   .-"-.   /      /      |       .-"-.
.-"     "-/      /       |    .-"     "-.
|-.     .-"\    /        |   /"-.     .-|
|  '-.-"    \  /         | /'    "-.-"  |
|     \      \/   .-"-.  /'        |    |
|      \      \.-"     "-.         |    |
|       \      |-.     .-"\        |    |
|        \     |  "-.-"    '\      |    |
|         \    |    |        '\    |    |
|    |\    \   |    |          '\  |    |
|    | \    \  |    |            '\|    |
|    |  \    \ |    |    :\.            |
|    |   \    \|    |    |  \.          |
|    |    \         |    |    \.        |
'-.  |  .-"\        |    |    '.\.    .-'
   "-|-"    \       |    |      "-\.-"
             \      |    |
              \     |    |
               "-.  |  .-'
                  "-|-"<?php }else{?>
              o
     o       /
      \     /
       \   /
        \ /
   ______________
  |.------------.|
  ||            ||
  ||            ||
  ||            ||
  ||            ||
  ||____________||_
  |OO ....... OO | `-.
  '------_.-._---' _.'
   _____||   ||___/_
  /  _.-|| N ||-._  \      .-._
 / -'_.---------._'- \    ,'___i-i___
/_.-'_  NINTENDO _'-._\  ' /_+  o :::\
|`-i /m\/m\|\|/=,/m\i-'| | || \ O / ||
|  |_\_/\_/___\_/'./|  | | \/  \ /  \/
`-'              '-.`-'  ,      V
                    `---' <?php }}?>
```

Thanks to @KevinCruijssen for a byte!

Comment: You can golf `$n==1` to `$n<2` for -1 byte. ;p

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Sweet, only a thousand and some to go!

Comment: `<?php` should be `<?` surely? And you can nudge right up to the opening php tag, so a whole 16 bytes!

Comment: This doesn't look like a serious entry to me.

Comment: @mbomb007 You think... ? The question also doesn't state standard loopholes so this is a perfectly valid answer (for now)

Comment: @BasicallyAlanTuring First of all, loopholes are disallowed [*by default*](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/34718) unless explictly allowed by the OP. Secondly, answers that don't make a serious golfing attempt are to be deleted. This answer doesn't even attempt to compact the strings.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 881 Bytes

```
<?=json_decode(gzinflate(base64_decode("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")),1)[$argv[1]];
```

Making of fill the lines with the graphics use the heredoc syntax in PHP

```
$a[1]=<<<A

A;
$a[2]=<<<B

B;
$a[3]=<<<C

C;
echo base64_encode(gzdeflate(json_encode($a)));
```